# How can I explicitely set a generic type in intellisense for javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, intellisense, jsdoc

I'm using d3.js v5 and VS Code intellisense via JSDoc for typechecking. I want to generate a line based on data with the type `Array<{ value: number }>`

I'm calling

```
const lineGenerator = d3
  .line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value);
  });
```

However, d3.line has 2 signature:

```js
export function line(): Line<[number, number]>;

export function line<Datum>(): Line<Datum>;
```

And VS Code's Intellisense is using the first one and complaining that `d.value` in invalid since `d` is of type `[number, number]`

In typescript, I'd be able to explicitely say

```js
const lineGenerator = d3
  .line<{ value: number}>()
  // ...
```

But i don't know how to do that with JSDoc and intellisense